# Confluence blueprint substitution does not work in macros with plain-text body

Tags: confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've created a Confluence blueprint plugin as per the basic/intermediate/advanced tutorials available from Atlassian. I now want to update the page template to include a `{HTML}` macro with embedded CDATA, where a URL in that CDATA contains a portion to be substituted with user-entered data.

What I'd ideally like to do, with the `<at:var...>` being substituted with `locationid`:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">
  <ac:plain-text-body>
    <![CDATA[<iframe src="http://...?locationid=<at:var at:name="locationid"/>"></iframe>]]>
  </ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

Unfortunately this does not work; the `<at:var at:name="...">` inside CDATA can't be substituted.

I've tried various formats of this, for example substituting in the entire CDATA string itself, even going as far as substituting in the entire `<ac:structured-macro>` block in a single string. None work.

A Google search brought up two very similar questions on the Atlassian community wiki, [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-can-i-get-a-template-variable-to-substitute-properly-in-a/qaq-p/465536) and [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-you-nest-Blueprint-placeholders-inside-a-macro-with-a/qaq-p/572422). Furthermore I found a [Confluence Server JIRA](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-30673) to fix this problem, but it's been rejected and closed.

Despite the evidence against a solution I'm hoping that someone creative has an idea of how I can achieve this?

**Atlassian SDK:** 6.2.14

Comment: Quit while youre ahead. It won't work 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking ;) but could it be the same as this discussion in our doc space?

[Confluence 4.3-RC1 Release Notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-4-3-rc1-release-notes-296092479.html?focusedCommentId=297669317&_ga=2.76435228.880695991.1502867105-570808541.1501665771#comment-297669317)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the relevance of this link. It's for a 5yo version of Confluence, and makes no mention of Blueprints or any aspect of my question. Can you please clarify which discussion you refer to that may be of use?